# I'm doing a http request in angular, my x-access-token showing up but request is unauthorized

Tags: node.js, angular, http, jwt

[image: Network image]

```
onTable(){
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
//headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
//headers.set('x-access-token', this.token).set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
console.log("this is header" + headers)
this.HttpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/read/all", {"headers": new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8').set('x-access-token', this.token)}).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res)
    
  }, err => {
    console.log(err)
  }
)
```

}

This is my function in angular. I'm quite a noob so i'm not sure if my content type should be json or x-www-form-urlencoded. In my image attached below my x-access-token has quotes around the token "", i'm wondering if this is the problem? Can anybody help me? The token is not wrong as when i try it in postman it works

For the record my backend configurations are
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'Bearer '+ token` in your request header.

```
onTable(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    //headers.set('x-access-token', this.token).set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log("this is header" + headers)
    this.HttpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/read/all", {"headers": new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8').set('x-access-token', 'Bearer '+ this.token)}).subscribe(
    res => {
        console.log(res)    
    }, err => {
        console.log(err)
    }
)}
```

Comment: Per OP's response, this worked except they needed to use an Authorization header instead of x-access-token...